# How to calculate sum of 2d vector by accessing objects

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, 2d-vector

I am working on an assignment where we must create vehicles, store them in a showroom, then store showrooms in a dealership. To do I have established, vector (Vehicle) carVector; in "Showroom.h", and vector(vector(Vehicle)) showroomVector; in "Dealsership.h"

at the moment I am trying to display the average price of a car in the dealership. my current function looks like this

```
float Dealership::GetAveragePrice() {

    vector<vector<Vehicle>> showroomVector;

    float sum = 0.0f;
    float avgSum = 0.0f;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;

    for (i = 0; i < showroomVector.size(); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < showroomVector.at(i).size(); j++) {
            sum = sum + showroomVector.at(i).at(j).GetPrice;
        }
    }
    avgSum = sum/((float)(i*j));

    return avgSum;
}
```

The getprice function is in Vehicle.cpp and it is the following

```
float Vehicle::GetPrice() {
    return this->price;
}
```

I basically need to add the price of every vehicle across all showrooms and then divide by i*j to find the average of the dealership but am having trouble accessing the data in my 2d vector correctly

Function that adds to showroom(was mentioned in the comments)

```
void Dealership::AddShowroom(Showroom s) {
        if (showroomVector.size() == capacity) {
            cout << "Dealership is full, can't add another showroom!\n";

        }

        else if (showroomVector.size() < capacity) {
            vector<Vehicle> s;
            showroomVector.push_back(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your example code puts no items at all into the local variable `showroomVector` so the sum should be 0.

Comment: `sum = sum + showroomVector.at(i).at(j).GetPrice;` is missing  `()` in the function call at the end.

Comment: `showroomVector.at(i).at(j).GetPrice;` is attempting  to add a pointer to your sum. Not sure if this is a copy paste error or what.

Comment: @drescherjm i have another function that adds to the showroom vector, just did not want to post anything unneccesary. Here it is

Comment: Was `showroomVector` supposed to be a class member or a local variable?

Comment: class member. i edited my post to show where i add to the showroom vector

Comment: I asked because your example code currently shows it as a local variable that has no elements.

Comment: @anastaciu i added the () but it is still not accessing any of elements and adding them. still getting zero. if i was going to add all the elements of a 2d vector would my syntax be correct

Comment: In the code you show `vector<Vehicle> s;` is added empty

Comment: Also keep the (), they are mandatory in a function call otherwise you'll be passing a fuction pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing, `vector<vector<Vehicle>> showroomVector;` should be a class member and not a function member.

As stated `GetPrice` is missing brackets in the call.

`Showroom s` parameter is never used in the `AddShowroom` function.

Here is a simplified possible implementation that would make some sense with some comments:

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hQ59s7hUgltdYgpY)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vehicle {

    float price;  

public:
    Vehicle(int price) : price(price) {} //ctor for sample

    float GetPrice() {
        return this->price;
    }
};

//for test purposes
class Showroom {

public:
    std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles = {Vehicle(500), Vehicle(1000), Vehicle(2350)};
};

class Dealership {
    std::vector<std::vector<Vehicle>> showroomVector;
    size_t capacity = 15;

public:
    //your function, unaltered, except for the brackets
    float GetAveragePrice() { 

        float sum = 0.0f;
        float avgSum = 0.0f;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        unsigned int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < showroomVector.size(); i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < showroomVector.at(i).size(); j++) {
                sum = sum + showroomVector.at(i).at(j).GetPrice();
            }
        }
        avgSum = sum / ((float)(i * j));

        return avgSum;
    }

    //Showroom parameter is never used
    //a logic move would be to have a vector of vehicles in each showroom
    void AddShowroom(Showroom s) {
        if (showroomVector.size() == capacity) {
            std::cout << "Dealership is full, can't add another showroom!\n";
            return;
        }

        if (showroomVector.size() < capacity) {   //add all prices of vehicles in showroom
            showroomVector.push_back(s.vehicles);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Dealership d;
    Showroom s;
    d.AddShowroom(s); //add a showroom
    Showroom s2;
    d.AddShowroom(s); //add another

    std::cout << d.GetAveragePrice();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```